# Using bootstrap grid system for vertical blocks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, grid

I just started to code the first block of my site for news, this block has height: 100%, and I want 3 blocks with photos of news.
Just like on http://fcbayern.com 
Can I do this with the bootstrap grid?

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using? put the code that you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using following code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;height: 200px;">Block 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="background-color:green;height: 100px;">Block 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;height: 100px;">Block 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good solution, but I have bootstrap 4 now, have you a solution for that?